# What is sprayed on chromatography paper when developing?

Tags: chromatography

When developing the chromatography paper, what chemical will you use to spray on the chromatography paper?

Comment: Are you trying to stain particular classes of compounds? Some reagents are quite specific. Most of the reagents I used in the lab were tailored to be used in tlc with silica (or aluminium oxide) on aluminium (or glass) plates. These reagents aren't necessarily compatible with paper.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you will use the chromatography paper for. Different testable substances will require different mediums. However, for a plain-simple chromatography without staining/substance identification, aluminium oxide (or silica) coated on a plate is used, however paper can also be used.